# Is there a way I can manage git on a remote computer using a GUI?

Tags: git, remote, gui

I am trying to find a way to manage a git repo on a server that is on a VPS. I have SSH which is all well and good, but I am looking for some way to use a GUI over a remote connection. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage"? Is your working directory on the VPS, or is the VPS hosting a second copy of your repo?

Comment: What I need is a way to control git on the server from my laptop, I am using the server to compile linux kernels and other things that need more power than my laptop can give. I am really looking to remotely control git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VNC or SSH ForwardX11 depending how good connectivity you have and how do you feel better

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, does X11 forwarding work if server I am connecting to does not have X installed? Or do both sides (my laptop and the VPS server) require X installed?

Comment: Your laptop needs X11 running of course to show graphical UI. In VPS you need only some X11 libs that are required for programs you plan to run. Use **ldd /program/name** to see what is needed

Comment: That sounds like it would work very well, I will give it a try. Thanks